# HtmlHelper Inside RazorEngine Templates

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper, razorengine

I am using [RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine) in my MVC app inside `HtmlHelper` extensions, as so:

MyHtmlHelpers.cs:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyTextBox(this HtmlHelper helper, string label, string value)
{
    var model = new { id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), label = label, value = value};
    string view = @"
        <label for=""@Model.id"">@Model.label</label>
        <input id=""@Model.id"" name=""@Model.id"" type=""text"" value=""@Model.value"" placeholder=""@Model.label"" />
    ";
    string renderedView = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(view, "MyTextBox", model: model);
    return new MvcHtmlString(renderedView);
}
```

which I use in *.cshtml as so:

```
@Html.MyTextBox("Enter Some Text", "")
```

That all works great. However, it breaks down when I try to nest a helper inside another helper, as so:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyName(this HtmlHelper helper, string firstName, string lastName)
{
    var model = new { firstName = firstName, lastName = lastName };
    string view = @"
        @Html.MyTextBox(""First Name"", @Model.firstName)
        @Html.MyTextBox(""Last Name"", @Model.lastName)
    ";
    string renderedView = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(view, "MyName", model: model);
    return new MvcHtmlString(renderedView);
}
```

The above gives me

> The name 'Html' does not exist in the current context

when I try to do

```
@Html.MyName("Peter", "Griffin")
```

which I think is because RazorEngine does not support the `@Html` like MVC does. (The above error is not specific to my own HtmlHelper or the fact that it calls the RazorEngine, but happens for any usage of `@Html`.)

Is there any way around this? I want to be able to nest such helpers an arbitrary number of layers deep, and therefore need to be able to use the `@Html` to its full capability inside RazorEngine templates. Or is RazorEngine just not a good route for this? I am a bit of a RazorEngine noob so bear with me.

Comment: Are the `MyTextBox` and the `MyName` helpers in the same namespace?

Comment: Yes they are...

Comment: Option 1: Create the view (as a real file) so that the generated class has the references, Option 2: Call the html helpers outside of the view to generate the view string and then call the Engine.

Comment: @IvayloStoev I have already done Option 1 (and use a strongly-typed `@model` in the file) -- I had omitted this from the OP for simplicity. I still get the same error when I try to add a reference to the `Html` object in the file (`@using System.Web.Mvc;`). Am I misunderstanding? Option 2 -- what do you mean? To my understanding, the whole point of creating HtmlHelpers is to use them from razor views. If I can't call them from views, I might as well just use `TagBuilder`s et al. (which I'm really trying to avoid) - https://stackoverflow.com/a/18472407/6627860

Comment: Forget what i wrote, you actually need a way to add the missing references. Look here: https://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/ReferenceResolver.html

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't use HtmlHelper, but achieves a similar result:

```
public class MyHelper
{
    public static string MyTextBox(string label, string value)
    {
        var model = new { id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), label = label, value = value};
        string view = @"
            <label for=""@Model.id"">@Model.label</label>
            <input id=""@Model.id"" name=""@Model.id"" type=""text"" value=""@Model.value"" placeholder=""@Model.label"" />
        ";
        string renderedView = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(view, "MyTextBox", model: model);
        return renderedView;
    }

    public static string MyName(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        var model = new { firstName = firstName, lastName = lastName };
        string view = @"
            @Raw(MyHelper.MyTextBox(""First Name"", @Model.firstName))
            @Raw(MyHelper.MyTextBox(""Last Name"", @Model.lastName))
        ";
        string renderedView = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(view, "MyName", model: model);
        return renderedView;
    }
}
```

Change summary:

- Change return type to string
- Remove extension parameter
- Replaced @Html reference with below
- Move into own helper class

Use like this:

```
@Raw(MyHelper.MyName("Peter", "Griffin"))
```

Ref: https://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/Encoding.html