# How can i make custom HTML Helper?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

how can I made custom HTML Helper Like `Html.CheckBoxFor()` 
i making dynamic form inputs that depend on the database,
so I need to generate my custom HTML Elements

I tried returning `PartialView` via `ajax request` and add the returned
 `HTML` of `PartialView` to the `DOM` , but it takes more time depending on the server-side

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "@Url.Action("FindTransactionForInternal", "Transactions")",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: { transId:transId },
            success: function (response) {
                $('#internaldetails').html(response);
           }
        });
```

Comment: Just extend the htmlhelper: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods.  If it doesn't need the html helper, then just make your own static method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating custom Html Helper: MyHelperFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18472128/creating-custom-html-helper-myhelperfor)

Comment: Please do search before asking; I found that by simply searching for "create custom html helper [asp.net-mvc]".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an example of how to made a custom HTML Helper

```
public static class HelpersExtensions
{
    public static string CustomCheckBoxFor(this HtmlHelper helper, string target, string text)
    {
        return String.Format("<input type='checkbox' for='{0}'>{1}</input>", target, text);
    }
}
```

Notes: Html helpers can't get info from database, just can use values passed trought parameters.

What could be done is get info in the controller and pass to model, so model pass parameters to custom html helper

Comment: checkboxes don't have a for attribute, a closing tag or text inside it like that.  Also if you are not using the html helper, you should really just make a static method rather than an extension method of something you are not using.  Finally, you can pretty much do what you want inside the method so you could go off to the db if you wanted, it would just be really expensive as it would be making a db call each time you used it